# Multiply elementwise array and rectangular matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to multiply elementwise an array of shape (10,) and a matrix of shape (10,20), basically multiply each column by the array.

But I got

> `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,) (20,10)`

It does work when I use a (10,10) matrix and a (10,) array.

I'd prefer not to do it with a `for` loop to optimize the time taken by my algorithm. (this array/matrix opreation is far deep in many other loops)

Comment: Do `arr1[:,None]*arr2`.

Comment: For broadcasting to work, you have to reshape the array with shape (10,) to (10, 1).  Divakar's suggestion will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule of broadcasting is that the arrays with fewest dimensions get expanded - and the expansion occurs at the front of the array.

In the (10,) * (10,20) case, there are 2 dim, so the first expands to (1,10).  But that can't be changed to match (10,20).

So you need to explicitly change the (10,) to (10,1).  The easiest way with `None`.

```
x[:,None]*y
```

Note, in MATLAB that expansion occurs at the other end.  But I'm not sure if MATLAB has broadcasting yet.  Octave added it some years ago.

================

In the (10,) * (10,10) case, => (1,10)*(10,10) => (10,10)

```
In [1403]: np.arange(4)*np.ones((4,4),int)
Out[1403]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])

In [1404]: np.arange(4)[:,None]*np.ones((4,4),int)
Out[1404]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Different results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply 2 matrix they have to have an order in math and in programs

```
A => a x n 
B => n x b
```

and you get `C = A x B` will be shaped  `C => a x b`

so your first array has to be (1,10) to multiply a matrix (10,20) and you will get an array (1,20)

to do that you can [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) your first array

Comment: You are describing matrix multiplication, not element wise multiplication.